# Can you move/copy Azure virtual machines to a different instance?

Tags: azure

If I setup a server running my application on an [azure instance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/#Windows), for example A1 can I later change the instance to D2?

I might want to experiment with a VM at a lower cost but then move to a higher performing machine at a later date without having to rebuild everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can [change the size of Azure VM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn168976%28v=nav.70%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on demand. Changing the size will trigger a machine reboot and if you're using a configuration with SSD temporary drive, the content of the SSD will get erased. Other than that, everything else will be left untouched.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. 1) you cannot always move/resize from one series to another series. 2) temp drives are at risk regardless whether they're SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Drew, the Principal PM in this area has a great blog [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resize-virtual-machines/) about this.

You can only resize a VM to another offering that does not have fundamentally different hardware. Since A-Series and D-Series VMs have similar hardware, you would be able to swap those two around. You would not be able to go from A-Series to G-Series though. In addition you need to look at VM availability per region if you want to swap to something only in certain areas, as well as look at if you are using an ASM or ARM VM.

If you have an existing VM, you can check what it can swap out with in the new portal under "Size" in the VM Settings.

[image]

This will allow you to reboot into a different machine type, however any temp storage will be erased as with any VM reboot. You just need to ensure you are storing your persistent data in external storage.

You can learn more about the VM size offerings [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/?b=16.18).